# Where is linked_portal_door in the Source SDK?

Tags: source-engine

I just made a new mod in the Source SDK. I saw online that there is an entity that allows portals to be created (`linked_portal_door`). However, I cannot find or create this entity.

Is it included in the base SDK or do you have to have an add-on. If it is not included, is there an alternative?

I am using Source Engine 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Linked_portal_door), `linked_portal_door` was added with Portal 2.

It sounds like your version of the SDK and toolset is too old to have it, and there is no alternative that I am aware of (the releated `prop_linked_portal_door` is also only available in Portal 2).